# How do I use =importfeed to import a selection of items from a period of time?

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to report on activity for a series of discuss groups that have an RSS feed available. I'd like to use =importfeed to return the data, but specify the range of time (ex: last 30 days), and the count of articles. Effectively, I'm trying to surface which groups are the most active vs not.

I have read through help articles and haven't come across this scenario or a solution. Any ideas?

TIA

References:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093337?hl=en

No field for count or date range